# expected class name before "{" token error

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

Well, I've checked for missing semicolons, and to my knowledge I don't have any inclusion loops, so I'm kind of stumped. I've been looking at other examples posted and I still don't quite see what I'm missing. I'm going to guess it's something to do with the use of templates that I'm not dealing with right, but I really don't know.

```
In file included from customtester.cpp:6:0:
MyBSTree.h:23:1: error: expected class-name before â{â token
```

File:

```
#ifndef MYBSTREE_H
#define MYBSTREE_H

template <typename T>        //not sure which of these I need,
class AbstractBSTree;        //the include, the forward
#include "abstractbstree.h"  //declaration, or both.

template <typename T>
class TreeNode
{
    T m_data;
    TreeNode<T> * m_right;
    TreeNode<T> * m_left;

};

template <typename T>
class MyBSTree:public AbstractBSTree //this would be line 23
{
    TreeNode<T> * m_root;
    int m_size;
};

#endif
```

Anything I'm missing? I cannot modify "abstractbstree.h"

Comment: FYI, usually including header files is first in the file.

Comment: where is this class "AbstractBSTree" defined?

Comment: AbstractBSTree is defined in abstractbstree.h, it's a pure virtual template class. Glenn caught what i was missing below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
public AbstractBSTree<T>
```

the compiler will assume the `<T>` only inside a template body and only for the templated class, not in public space

Comment: That would be it. I thought it might be something I was forgetting with templates. Thanks.

Comment: @user2995084 and you need the class definition, not just the forward declaration. Presumably that is in the header you are asking about including.

Comment: @juanchopanza - we can safely assume that it is in the include file

Comment: You can't safely assume anything.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `<T>`.

Since AbstractBSTree is a template class, you need to specify the template parameter when you derive from it for MyBSTree:

```
template <typename T>
class MyBSTree:public AbstractBSTree<T>  // <-- Use <T> here
{
    TreeNode<T> * m_root;
    int m_size;
};
```